# Getting invalid clicks on AdSense ads - Never seen this before

Tags: adsense

My website is getting invalid clicks on Ads. This month's [Adsense Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccFVs.png)  shows that 483 clicks were generated from the UK, Albania and Germany via tablet devices.

On adsense Report 379 clicks from the UK. On Google Analytics, only 20 visitors entered the website from the UK through a tablet device this month.

The weird thing is that the ad units get clicks with no impressions or page-views from tablet devices. And they also get clicks even-though they are removed from the website.

Is there any possible way to track the IP of those clicks? What am I facing here? and how to stop it?

Comment: I've been facing the same problem for the last few months. You should probably fill out this form: https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/invalid_clicks_contact

Answer (score 0):

Google has [acknowledged](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6090783?hl=) that statistics from AdSense and Analytics may vary. One possible solution could be to install a heatmap on your website, I suggest [Hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/). You could also try to stop eventual bots from entering your website with a hidden [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) (v3).